# cargar datos del usuario al iniciar sesión - react-native

Tags: php, react-native

**tengo un login creado con react-native y funciona correctamente, al iniciar sesión consulta la API e inicia sesión sin problemas, pero ahora al iniciar sesión estoy tratando de que me muestre el numero de documento o cualquier dato del usuario en mi screen pero no lo he logrado hacer, la Api esta en php y la base de datos en mysql. Si alguien me puede colaborar se lo agradecería, ya que lo único que necesito es poder ver el numero de documento del usuario cuando inicia sesión en mi screen, tengo todo pero no he logrado traer los datos a mi context.

**envió adicional todo el proyecto de react-native y la api de php :**
https://github.com/Giovannychvz/login

**AuthContext.tsx**

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

type AuthContextProps = {
    errorMessage: string;
    token: string | null;
    user: Usuarios | null;
    status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
    signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
    signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
    logOut: () => void;
    removeError: () => void;

}

const authInicialState: AuthState = {
    status:'checking',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    errorMessage:'',
    
}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

    const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);

    useEffect(() =>{
        checkToken();
    }, [])

    const checkToken = async () =>{
       const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

       //No token, no autenticado
       if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
      
       //hay token
       //AQUI ES DONDE DEBERIA LLAMAR A LA API PARA MOSTRAR EL DATO DEL DDOCUMENTO DE USUARIO - https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcerousuarios/user-info.php
       
      const resp = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');
          
       if(resp.status !== 200){
          return dispatch({type:'notAuthenticated'});
       }

       await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resp.data.token)
      

       dispatch({
           type: 'signUp',
           payload:{
               token: resp.data.token,
               user: resp.data.usuarios
           }
           
       })   
      
    }


   const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
       
        try {

     await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php',
    {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-Type': 'application/json'
 
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"email":correo, "password" : password})
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(resData => {
       if(resData.message == "Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.") {

      

        dispatch({
            type: 'signUp',
            payload: {
                token: resData.token,
                user: resData.usuarios
            }
          
        }); 
       }else{
        Alert.alert(resData.message)
       }
       
    });
      
           }catch (error) {
            dispatch({type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
           }
    };

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            signIn, 
            removeError,
        }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

**ESTE ES MI SCREEN**

ProtectedScreen.tsx

```js
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Button, Image, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'


//AQUI IMPORTO EL CONTEXT
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'
import { loginStyles } from '../theme/LoginTheme'


interface Props extends StackScreenProps<any, any>{}

export const ProtectedScreen = ({navigation}: Props) => {

  //AQUI LLAMO USER PARA QUE ME MUESTRE POSTERIORMETE LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO AL INICIAR SESIÓN
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
     
         <View>
             
         
    
 
         <Text>
                  //INTENTO CARGAR TODO LO RELACIONADO CON EL USURIO Y TAMPOCO CARGA NADA
                {JSON.stringify( user, null, 5) }
            </Text>
            <Text>
            //INTENTO CARGAR EL DOCUMENTO DEL USUARIO PERO NO CARGA
         {user.documento}
            </Text>
     
       </View>
    
         
 
         </View>
    

    </>
  )
}
```

//ESTA ESLA API
user-info.php

```js
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    require __DIR__.'/classes/Database.php';
    require __DIR__.'/middlewares/Auth.php';

    $allHeaders = getallheaders();
    $db_connection = new Database();
    $conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();
    $auth = new Auth($conn,$allHeaders);

    $returnData = [
        "success" => 0,
        "status" => 401,
        "message" => "Unauthorized"
    ];

    if($auth->isAuth()){
        $returnData = $auth->isAuth();
    }

    echo json_encode($returnData);
```

```
Auth.php
```

```js
        <?php
        require __DIR__.'/../classes/JwtHandler.php';
        class Auth extends JwtHandler{

            protected $db;
            protected $headers;
            protected $token;
            public function __construct($db,$headers) {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->db = $db;
                $this->headers = $headers;
            }

            public function isAuth(){
                if(array_key_exists('Authorization',$this->headers) && !empty(trim($this->headers['Authorization']))):
                    $this->token = explode(" ", trim($this->headers['Authorization']));
                    if(isset($this->token[1]) && !empty(trim($this->token[1]))):
                        
                        $data = $this->_jwt_decode_data($this->token[1]);

                        if(isset($data['auth']) && isset($data['data']->user_id) && $data['auth']):
                            $user = $this->fetchUser($data['data']->user_id);
                            return $user;

                        else:
                            return null;

                        endif; // End of isset($this->token[1]) && !empty(trim($this->token[1]))
                        
                    else:
                        return null;

                    endif;// End of isset($this->token[1]) && !empty(trim($this->token[1]))

                else:
                    return null;

                endif;
            }

            protected function fetchUser($user_id){
                try{
                //ESTOS SON LOS DATOS QUE DEBERIA CARGARME EN MI SCREEN AL INICIAR SESIÓN EN REACT-NATIVE
                    $fetch_user_by_id = "SELECT `name`,`email`, `tipo_usuario` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `id`=:id";
                    $query_stmt = $this->db->prepare($fetch_user_by_id);
                    $query_stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query_stmt->execute();

                    if($query_stmt->rowCount()):
                        $row = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        return [
                            'success' => 1,
                            'status' => 200,
                            'user' => $row
                        ];
                    else:
                        return null;
                    endif;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

login.php

```js
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

function msg($success,$status,$message,$extra = []){
    return array_merge([
        'success' => $success,
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    ],$extra);
}

require __DIR__.'/classes/Database.php';
require __DIR__.'/classes/JwtHandler.php';

$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$returnData = [];

// IF REQUEST METHOD IS NOT EQUAL TO POST
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"):
    $returnData = msg(0,404,'Page Not Found!');

// CHECKING EMPTY FIELDS
elseif(!isset($data->email) 
    || !isset($data->password)
    || empty(trim($data->email))
    || empty(trim($data->password))
    ):

    $fields = ['fields' => ['email','password']];
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Por favor, llene todos los campos obligatorios!',$fields);

// IF THERE ARE NO EMPTY FIELDS THEN-
else:
    $email = trim($data->email);
    $password = trim($data->password);
    $tipo_usuario = trim($data->tipo_usuario);

    // CHECKING THE EMAIL FORMAT (IF INVALID FORMAT)
    /*if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
        $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Email no existe!');*/
    
    // IF PASSWORD IS LESS THAN 8 THE SHOW THE ERROR
    if(strlen($password) < 4):
        $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Su contraseña debe tener al menos 8 caracteres!');

    // THE USER IS ABLE TO PERFORM THE LOGIN ACTION
    else:
        try{
            
            $fetch_user_by_email = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `email`=:email";
            $query_stmt = $conn->prepare($fetch_user_by_email);
            $query_stmt->bindValue(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_stmt->execute();

            // IF THE USER IS FOUNDED BY EMAIL
            if($query_stmt->rowCount()):
                $row = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $check_password = password_verify($password, $row['password']);

                // VERIFYING THE PASSWORD (IS CORRECT OR NOT?)
                // IF PASSWORD IS CORRECT THEN SEND THE LOGIN TOKEN
                if($check_password):

                    $jwt = new JwtHandler();
                    $token = $jwt->_jwt_encode_data(
                        'http://localhost/php_auth_api/',
                        array("user_id"=> $row['id'])
                    );
                    
                    $returnData = [
                        'success' => 1,
                        'message' => 'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.',
                        'token' => $token
                    ];

                // IF INVALID PASSWORD
                else:
                    $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Contraseña invalida!');
                endif;

            // IF THE USER IS NOT FOUNDED BY EMAIL THEN SHOW THE FOLLOWING ERROR
            else:
                $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Acceso de usuario no válido!');
            endif;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $returnData = msg(0,500,$e->getMessage());
        }

    endif;

endif;

echo json_encode($returnData);
```